# Windows Palo Alto Cortex XDR BSOD with Bug Check 0x139

Tags: windows, debugging, antivirus, bsod

The Windows antivirus `Cortex XDR Agent version 8.1.1` is active on my dev machine.
While running some snapshots of specified processes using [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), suddenly Cortex popped up a message saying `Malicious tampering threat detected` followed by a BSOD

[image: bsod]

After a few hours of debugging, here's the minimal reproduction

```
// HeapTest.c - Release x64 build with Visual C++ 2022 
// BSOD with Bug Check 0x139 in Cortex XDR

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int main()
{
    CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST, 8456);
}
```

where process ID 8456 is for [cytray.exe](https://docs-cortex.paloaltonetworks.com/r/Cortex-XDR/7.8/Cortex-XDR-Agent-Administrator-Guide/Troubleshooting-Resources-for-Windows).

[image: xdr]

Windows created a minidmp in `%SystemRoot%\Minidump` and opening it with the `Windbg` debugger shows

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\090223-14718-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 22621 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff807`72600000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff807`732130e0
Debug session time: Sat Sep  2 19:35:12.743 2023 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 5:06:37.745
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
...................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 139, {a, 0, 0, fffff80772a2dfc0}

Probably caused by : Unknown_Image ( PAGE_NOT_ZERO )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

 *** Memory manager detected 178688 instance(s) of page corruption, target is likely to have memory corruption.



6: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unknown bugcheck code (139)
Unknown bugcheck description
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000000a
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: fffff80772a2dfc0

Debugging Details:
------------------


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x139

PROCESS_NAME:  HeapTest.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

BAD_PAGES_DETECTED: 2ba00

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80772a3bf8e to fffff80772a31250

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffa20c`050b6988 fffff807`72a3bf8e : 00000000`00000139 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffa20c`050b6990 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!guard_icall_bugcheck+0x1e


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  PAGE_NOT_ZERO

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  PAGE_NOT_ZERO

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

 *** Memory manager detected 178688 instance(s) of page corruption, target is likely to have memory corruption.
```

Based upon the prevention information from Cortex

```
OS version: 10.0.22621
Component: Anti Tampering Protection
Cortex XDR code: C04000AC
Prevention description: Malicious tampering threat detected
Verdict: 0
Quarantined: False
Post-Detected: False
Rule name: anti_tampering.8
```

it's mostly likely a bug in one of the following [Cortex XDR Drivers](https://docs-cortex.paloaltonetworks.com/r/Cortex-XDR/7.8/Cortex-XDR-Agent-Administrator-Guide/Troubleshooting-Resources-for-Windows)

```
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cyverak.sys
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cyvrmtgn.sys
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cyvrfsfd.sys
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\tedrdrv.sys
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\tdevflt.sys
C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\tedrpers-<version>.sys
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\telam.sys
```

**Question**

Out of curiosity, is there a way to identify the name of the buggy sys driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Out of curiosity, is there a way to identify the name of the buggy sys driver?

No reasonable way without the source code for the drivers.  Memory corruption is something that happened *before* the crash.  And it's a debugging exercise that really would require the driver developer to figure out.